# Q: example involving almost continuous everywhere function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I need an example of two functions $f$ and $g$ verifying the following properties:

- $f$ defined on $\left[0,1\right]$ $\times$ $\left[0,1\right]$ and continuous almost everywhere.
- $g$ continous everywhere and not equal to $f$ almost everywhere.

I can't get with any example so if someone could help me I would be so grateful.

Comment: Does "almost continuous everywhere" mean "continuous almost everywhere"? Does "almost equal to $f$" mean "equal to $f$ almost everywhere"?

Comment: @angryavian yes. Sorry, my english is not really good

Comment: What does "not almost equal to f" mean? Why can't we take $f\equiv 1,$ $g\equiv 0?$

Comment: This got asked yesterday also. Why don't you say what the domain and codomain of the function need to be ?

Comment: @Jorge because the problem doesn't mention it. I'm asking this question because neither I understand the problem itself

Comment: Are you sure that you copied it correctly? Because two different constant functions satisfy this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are asking for so please tell me if this helps:

Take $f:[0,1]\times[0,1]$, $f(x,y):=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{q} & , x=\frac{p}{q}\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}, \text{ with } p\in\mathbb{Z} \text{ and } q\in\mathbb{N} \text{ coprime}\\ 0 & ,\text{if } x\in[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function)
so here you basically ignore the $y$-component.
Then $f$ is continuous for all irrational $x$.
And take $g(x,y):=0$.